# Play framework JPA problem with save()

Tags: java, sql, jpa, persistence, playframework

I'm trying to save a simple object in the database, but it's giving me problems.

This is my object class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="lines")
public class Line extends GenericModel{

    @Id
    @Column(name="line_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="line_text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name="line_postid")
    private int postid;

    @Column(name="line_position")
    private int position;
}
```

And this is what I have in my controller:

```
Line l = new Line();
l.setPosition(0);
l.setPostid(4);
l.setText("geen");
l.save();
```

I'm doing the exact same thing for other Models, and I'm having no problems, only this one is giving me problems. When I refresh the browser I get:
`PersistenceException occured : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update`

I also added `jpa.debugSQL=true` to my configuration, and in my console I'm getting:

`Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lines (line_position, line_postid, line_text, line_id) values (0, 4, 'geen', 0)' at line 1`

And the browser is also showing this: `This exception has been logged with id 66k3glbb6` but I have no idea where I can view my logs, so if someone could tell me that too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lines` is a reserved word in MySQL, you need to escape it as follows:

```
@Table(name="`lines`") // Hibernate way
```

or

```
@Table(name="\"lines\"") // JPA standard way
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure there is no `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` for save method :)